# Jquery - three select lists, deactivate the other two if one is value is selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I have three drop down select lists, when a value from one of the list is selected, I want the other two to be greyed out and inactive. I have id wrappers around each select list that I'm experimenting on, but as I am new with jquery I'm not getting very far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
  var $selects = $('#select1, #select2, #select3');
  $selects.change(function() {
    // disabled the other two
    $selects.not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

---

Updated version:

```
$(function() {
  var $selects = $('#select1, #select2, #select3');
  $selects.change(function() {
    // disable or enable the other two
    $selects.not(this).attr('disabled', $(this).val() === '' ? '' : 'disabled');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is very elegant and easy to understand. Each of the dropdown lists has a "None selected" option. The value there is just "". If you want the other fields to go active again if "None selected" is selected, how would you write it?

Comment: Added an updated version that should enable or disable the other two depending on the current value of the select that triggered the change event.  Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Simply fantastic! You had one too many = though, should be .val() ==. I take it that's a typo.

Comment: That was actually intentional.  The triple === means "don't do any type coercion in the comparison", which is pretty important when comparing to string values that may be empty.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Yesterday when I tried with triple, it didn't work. Today it does, I guess I had some kind of browser cache issue.

Comment: Strange... not sure why that initially didn't work for you. I was wrapping things up when I commented last night so I commented quickly, but if you were interested in more reading on == vs. ===, here's a previous SO post that sums it up pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#wrappers').change(function(){
  $('#select1').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#select2').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Where `wrappers` is the id of select element from which when you choose a value the other two get disabled whose id is `select1` and `select2` respectively eg:

```
<select id="wrappers">.........
<select id="select1">.........
<select id="select2">.........
```

[Here is working example](http://jsbin.com/eqiko3/2)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have three, and if any of the three are selected, the other two should disable.

```
function toggleOthers(x) {
var select = new Array('#wrapper1','#wrapper2','#wrapper3');

for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++ )
    if ($(x).attr('id')!=select[i])
        $(x).attr('disabled','disable');
}
```

HTML:
`<select onchange='toggleOthers(this);' id='wrapper1'> etc...`

Answer (score 0):

if you have the selects with a div wrapper with an id of #wrapper

```
$('#wrapper select').each(function(i,select){
   $(select).change(function(){
        $(this).attr('class','enabled').siblings().attr('class','disabled');
    })
})
```